# String a Date con formato correcto

Tags: java, string, date

Tengo una duda, en cuanto a fechas se refiere en Java. Recibo varias fechas en formato String pero cada una de ellas viene en un formato distinto, de modo que no vienen en un formato determinado.

Fechas con formatos como:

- 21/05/2018Z09:14:32.123
- 21/05/2018
- 21-05-2018/09:14:32
- 21-05-2018 09:14:32

Y así un sinfín de fechas más...

El objetivo es pasar dichas fechas a un formato concreto. que sería el siguiente: 
2018-05-21 09:14:32 --> (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss).

No sé si es que no entiendo el SimpleDateFormat correctamente, pero no consigo devolver la fecha en el formato que deseo.

```
    Date fecha = new Date("2018-01-23T09:56:04+01:00");
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String strDate = sdf.format(fecha);
            Date dates = new Date();  
            try {

                dates = dateFormat.parse(strDate);
                System.out.println(sdf.format(dates));
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
//
                }
```

Comment: El ejemplo que has pasado es que hace lo contrario, a ver, metes la fecha ya en el formato deseado y la pasas a otros formatos distintos, lo suyo para probar es hacer lo mismo que tienes pero al revés, meter la fecha en el formato que no se desea y pasarlo al que sí se quiere. El simpleDateFormat es el que debe tener el formato deseado. PD: HOLA JAVIVO

Comment: Te paso una página con ejemplos de como va el simpledateformat, no sé si es exactamente lo que buscas pero creo que valdria:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Javivo. ¿tienes todos los formatos posibles que puedes recibir? Te pregunto porque si los tienes sí hay solución mediante SimpleDateFormat, pero si no tienes los formatos no veo como.

Answer (score 1):

En resumen, recibes varias fechas en distintos formatos en String, y lo que quieres es cambiar el formato de la fecha que recibes. De ser así sigue los siguientes pasos:

Lo primero que vamos a hacer es crear nuestras variables:

```
SimpleDateFormat conver = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date fecha;
private String nuevoFormato;
```

La variable `conver` será para realizar la conversión al formato que deseas, la variable `fecha`, nos servirá para almacenar la conversión de String a Date, y posteriormente la variable `nuevoFormato`, será la conversión de Date a String nuevamente para obtener el formato que deseas.

Primero vamos a convertir las fechas strings que recibes a Date:

```
try {
    fecha = conver.parse(fechaQueRecibes);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    error("ERROR AL CONVERTIR FECHA", "CONVERTIR FECHA");
}
```

Vamos a colocar todo dentro de una excepción, por si llega a generar un error. Primero colocamos la variable `fecha` del tipo Date, para almacenar la fecha del tipo String que recibes en cualquier formato. Y usamos el `SimpleDateFormat` con su método `parse` para convertir de String a Date. Una vez obtenido esto, procedemos a convertir la fecha Date en String nuevamente **(si no requieres convertir la fecha a String, lo puedes dejar en este paso y quedarte con una fecha Date pero con el formato que deseas)**.

Para convertir de Date a String, usamos lo siguiente:

```
try {
        nuevaFormato = conver.format(fecha.getTime());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    error("ERROR AL CONVERTIR FECHA A TEXTO" + ex.getMessage(), "CONVERTIR FECHA A TEXTO");
}
```

Finalmente, utilizas la variable `nuevoFormato`, para almacenar la conversión de Date a String y listo.